# A month number must be between 1 and 12, Error<Month>

Tags: crystal-reports

Error in formula  . 
'Stringvar Array strings := Split({?@V2_month}, ",");'
A month number must be between 1 and 12.

Above is the error that i get, {?@V2_month} is my report parameter.

Month is my formula field
Below is the formula in the Month formula field

```
Stringvar Array strings := Split({?@V2_month}, ",");
Stringvar result := "" ;
//populate array

Numbervar i;
for i := 1 to Ubound(strings) 
do (
result := result + MonthName(ToNumber(strings[i]) , true)+", " ;
);
MID(result , 1 , len(result) - 2);
```

Any idea why this formula prompt this kind of error?

Comment: it works fine for me. I provided value as `1,3,5` and got answer as `Jan, Mar, May`

Comment: How are you providing data for parameter at runtime

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as yours. You forgot to add comma in your input values of the parameter `?@V2_month` making it more than 12 or less than 1. Make sure the value you entered is comma separated and number between 1 and 12.

[image: Click here to see image]

Comment: I'm sorry but where should i put the comma?   Stringvar Array strings := Split({?@V2_month}, ",");  In here?

Comment: @hunt, you need to separate the parameter value when the report is refreshed or run. See the attached screen shot in the answer. Also, make sure the value is less than 13 and greater than 0